# Configuring Graylog on Web.Config class

Tags: asp.net, web-config, serilog, .net-4.8, graylog

I want to configure Graylog in web.Config file but for some reason, logs are not being sent. **(configuring on JSON is not an option):**

```
<add key="serilog:using:Graylog" value="Serilog.Sinks.Graylog" />
<add key="serilog:write-to:Graylog.hostnameOrAdress" value="URL" />
<add key="serilog:write-to:Graylog.port" value="12201" />
<add key="serilog:write-to:Graylog.transportType" value="Http" />
```

But I checked and I am able to send logs to Graylog if i configure it in my Serilog Init class

```
var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .ReadFrom.AppSettings().WriteTo.Graylog(new GraylogSinkOptions
    {
        HostnameOrAddress = "URL",
        Port = 12201,
        TransportType = TransportType.Http
    })
    .CreateLogger();
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found out my mistake. Made a typo: instead of address I wrote adress :)

wrong:

```
<add key="serilog:write-to:Graylog.hostnameOrAdress" value="URL" />
```

should be:

```
<add key="serilog:write-to:Graylog.hostnameOrAddress" value="URL" />
```